# What is the current standard with regards to "fighting words"?

Tags: united-states, freedom-of-speech, first-amendment

Since Street v. New York, the Supreme Court has significantly narrowed the grounds on which speech can be considered "fighting words" and thus could legally be banned.  In Collin v. Smith, SCOTUS held that Nazis marching in uniform and displaying swastikas through a neighborhood of Holocaust survivors was protected speech.  In Snyder v. Phelps, SCOTUS held that protesting against dead soldiers at their funerals, including signs that Phelps himself said were intentionally outrageous was protected speech.

So if I can march around a Jewish neighborhood in an SS uniform, and I can shout about how dead soldiers are burning in hell at their funerals, what *can't* I do?  What are some examples of speech that is not protected due to being classified as "fighting words"?

Comment: Shortly after the Columbia disaster, Phelps and his deplorable Westboro Baptist Church crew decided to protest just outside the main gate of the Johnson Space Center. "God struck down the Columbia!", and I won't write the even worse signs they bandied about other than to say they were full of vile, vulgar, ignorant, and hateful words. I knew one of the astronauts who died with that disaster. After getting over being rather angry, that is when I started donating money to the ACLU. Freedom of speech is not about tolerating speech one agrees with. It is about tolerating speech one disagrees with.

Comment: @DavdHammen I absolutely agree.  You don't need constitutional protections to say things people agree with.

Answer (score 7):

The content of the "fighting words" doctrine seems to be reduced to certain personal insults, and the term plays a minimal role in court rulings. In [Snyder v. Phelps](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/562/443/), the expression is used twice, once referring to the position of the dissent, and once in scare quotes where it is a third-generation quote from Chaplinsky (and at any rate, the conclusion was "this isn't that"). [Virginia v. Black](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/538/343/), 538 U.S. 343 seems to be the most recent positive invocation of the concept by SCOTUS:

> a State may punish those words "which by their very utterance inflict
> injury or tend to incite an immediate breach of the peace." Chaplinsky
> v. New Hampshire, supra, at 572; see also [R. A. V. v. City of St.
> Paul](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/505/377/#tab-opinion-1959076), supra, at 383 (listing limited areas where the First Amendment
> permits restrictions on the content of speech). *We have consequently
> held that fighting words-"those personally abusive epithets which,
> when addressed to the ordinary citizen, are, as a matter of common
> knowledge, inherently likely to provoke violent reaction" -are
> generally proscribable under the First Amendment*. [Cohen v. California](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/403/15/),
> 403 U. S. 15, 20 (1971); see also Chaplinsky v. New Hampshire

I find are no concrete examples of epithets held to be actual "fighting words" from the past 50 years. In [Chaplinsky](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/315/568/), it was held that

> the appellations "damned racketeer" and "damned Fascist" are epithets
> likely to provoke the average person to retaliation, and thereby cause
> a breach of the peace

There has been a steady retreat from this conclusion for almost 80 years. [Feiner v. New York](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/340/315/#tab-opinion-1940045), 340 U.S. 315 upheld a conviction for a provocative speech, making "derogatory remarks concerning President Truman, the American Legion, the Mayor of Syracuse, and other local political officials". The court found that the actual effect on the crowd was what mattered, not the content of the speech, and there *is* no report of what the "fighting words" were. [Texas v. Johnson](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/491/397/), 491 U.S. 397 dials the fighting words concept back further, to being words "likely to be seen as a direct personal insult or an invitation to exchange fisticuffs" – but Johnson did not utter fighting words, so again the court did not definitively point to any actual "fighting words".

Comment: I always thought "fighting words" as used here would necessarily apply only to a singular person, and thus the examples fall outside the parameter. But your references include the use against groups of people. Interesting.

Comment: so being a damned fascist is protected speech, but calling that person a damned fascist might not be? US free speech law is has some whack priorities...

Comment: Surely there are no words which *by their very utterance* inflict injury? Sure, a crowd can chant "HANG MIKE PENCE" but no injury is inflicted until Mike Pence is actually hanged?

Comment: @user253751 That would be a direct incitement to violence. Which is illegal.

Comment: @Rstew it still doesn't inflict injury *by its very utterance* so I wonder which kinds of speech fall in that category.

Comment: @Rstew I think it's also a death threat, which is separately illegal.  A death threat against the sitting Vice President is, again, itself [also separately illegal](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/871).

Comment: @user253751 Obviously words can't directly cause physical injury, but they can cause psychological injury. But in any case, the rest of the definition covers the injury that the utterance is likely to incite.

Comment: Presumably the simplest example of fighting words would be something like "I dare you to hit me" during a heated argument.

Comment: @user253751 Those rioters crossed a line. The line they crossed wasn't chanting "HANG MIKE PENCE". That would probably have been fine (legally fine, not morally fine) had the rioters remained outside the Capitol as peaceful protesters. Their speech became unprotected speech upon entering the Capitol and trying to to hunt down Mike Pence

Comment: @Tristan Being a fascist is perfectly legal in the US, at so long as those fascists aren't conspiring / acting to overthrow the country. Calling those damned fascists "fascists" would most certainly fall into the category of protected speech. Calling them "damned fascist" might or might not (IANAL). Nonsense statements such as Rep. Mo Brooks tweet that tried to pin the blame for the 6 Jan 2021 riot on "fascist ANTIFA" was protected speech. And the person who responded to Brook's tweet with a thinly veiled insult regarding Brook's intelligence: That too was protected speech.

Comment: @DavidHammen I am aware. I was not disputing the facts, but saying that I do not consider the priorities implied by them sound

Comment: To de-politicize this, I would say the lead up to Scotty throwing the first punch in an epic bar fight in the classic Star Trek episode "Trouble with Tribbles" is a perfect example of fighting words.  The Klingon wasn't getting anywhere with provoking the crew with his Klingon Nationalism or attacks on Kirk's character mostly because Scotty, the senior officer in the scene, was telling the rest of crew to ignore the insults.  When the Klingon sees that insulting the Enterprise was striking a nerve with Scotty, he makes a more insulting statement about the ship and Scotty responds with force.

Answer (score 0):

https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3762605

Here is a law review article with 15 relatively recent (compared to Chaplinsky) instances of fighting words being found by lower courts.  It also has an analysis of which words and  acts are most likely to cause a court to find fighting words.